# Dynamodb update attribute based on another

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, updates

I want to update an item in Dynamodb such that I can set the value of one attribute based on the value of an existing attribute in that item. For example: I have table with the following item `{"id": 1, "valueone": 30}`.

I want to update this item such that I can add another attribute `valuetwo` whose value is twice that of `valueone`: `{"id": 1, "valueone": 30, "valuetwo": 60}`

Something like this, but not sure how to represent `valueone` in the ExpressionAttributeValues:

```
table.update_item(Key={'id': 1}, UpdateExpression="set vtwo = :two * :r", ExpressionAttributeValues={':r': valueone, ':two': 2},ReturnValues="ALL_NEW"))
```

I can control whether `valuetwo` is a new attribute in the item or already exists with a dummy value (say zero).

Comment: how u acheived it in aws cli?

Answer (score 6):

Currently, DynamoDB doesn't support **" * - Multiply (or) / - Division"** arithmetic operators in `UpdateExpression`.

It supports only addition (+) and subtraction (-) operators.

**Addition:-**

```
UpdateExpression : "SET total_new_val = total_val + :value",
```

**Subtraction:-**

```
UpdateExpression : "SET total_new_val = total_val - :value",
```

**Multiplication:-**

```
UpdateExpression : "SET total_new_val = total_val * :value",
```

**Multiplication throws the below error:-**

```
Unable to update item. Error JSON: {
  "message": "Invalid UpdateExpression: Syntax error; token: \"*\", near: \"tota
l_val * :value\"",
  "code": "ValidationException",
  "time": "2017-02-07T11:32:41.478Z",
  "requestId": "64f36024-7251-40af-98ee-e9cef854e94b",
  "statusCode": 400,
  "retryable": false,
  "retryDelay": 0
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to get around this constraint by doing something like this: `table.update_item(Key={'id': 1}, UpdateExpression="set vtwo = :r", ExpressionAttributeValues={':r': valueone *2},ReturnValues="ALL_NEW"))`